# Access Provider from Service

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to access a provider that would normally be used in a config from a service? The reason for doing so is I don't have the information I need yet to be able to do it in the module.config.

The provider I would like to access is the $stateProvider which is part of the ui.router module. Lets say I have a module that is dependent on other modules. I would like to be able to have these dependencies register their "desired" routes/states with a service and then use the service determine which ones I actually register. I was hoping that this wouldn't have to be done in the config since I would effectively only be adding new states, not removing or modified those that are already there. So basically, I want my service to get a list of states/routes and have the service register them rather than doing it in the config.

Comment: More context? There are certain things you can only do in an `app.config` block and there are certain things you cannot do.  Can you post some code that will explain more of what you're trying to accomplish?  What "provider" do you need access to?  and why?

Comment: Updated, let me know if you need more.

Comment: As @tennisgent says, I don't think you'll be able to access any provider through normal injection after the configuration phase. Have you thought about just saving the provider to `window` during the configuration phase...not guaranteed to be clean or safe in the least, but it might work.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, but I tried the following:
`.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $window){
 $window.stateProvider = $stateProvider;
...
}`
and it didnt work. I got an error saying `unknown provider $window`. Is the window not available in the config?

Comment: I think @Andyrooger was more saying that you would bind to the native `window` object instead of the angular `$window` object.  The angular `$window` object won't be available in your config because angular hasn't finished its initialization phase.  So instead, try this: `.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ window.stateProvider = $stateProvider; ... }`

Comment: Pure genius, it works. If you want to put your comment as an answer, I'll check it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented:

You won't be able to inject a provider after the config phase. However you can inject during the config  phase and store the it somewhere until you need it.

For example

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    window.stateProvider = $stateProvider;
});

app.service('myService', function() {
    var $stateProvider = window.state provider;
    // ...
});
```

## Disclaimer(s)

Though I am suggesting this as a possibility, I am certainly not recommending it. It will make your code hard to test, and I doubt it's officially supported so there's no guarantee the provider will work even if you can access it.

That said, if you need to do this and it works then so be it. Just be sure to test vigorously! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the `ui.router` module, but I believe it has to be setup in the `config` because the routes have to be setup before the app is initiated.  From my understanding, it works basically the same as the `$routeProvider`, in that you have to setup everything you want to do in the config.

Its not explicitly said anywhere (that I can see), but the docs/examples found [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24route) seem to suggest that the `$routeProvider` can only be accessed from within a module declaration (ie `app.module('myMod', [], function($routeProvider){ ... })`) or inside of the `app.config` function.

I'm going to guess that the `$stateProvider` acts the same way.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the response. I'm going to keep looking though and see if I can find something more definitive.